# Contextmenus onclick AJAX POST doesnt work

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, google-chrome-extension

Help, i cant send data via ajax post to my nodejs server from contextmenus. It just does not work.

The ajax doesnt even give an error alert.

Ive tried to read the chrome ext dev page but i cant understand it.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Report a Scam Image",
    contexts:["image"],
    onclick: function(info) {

            var getUrl = info.srcUrl;
            alert(getUrl);

            $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8023/report",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        link: getUrl,
                    }

            }).done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {

                    alert("Error!!!!!!!");
            });

    }
});
```

The nodejs backend is expected to be working fine. its just this part that cannot work.

Comment: If your background script is declared with persistent: false, you need to use a separate single listener chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener, see the documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus#event-onClicked). There is not `onclick` event but there is `onClicked`.

Comment: chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Report a Scam Image",
    contexts:["image"],

});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info) {
 var getUrl = info.srcUrl;
 alert(getUrl);

 $.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:8023/report",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
    link: getUrl,
   }

 }).done(function(data) {
  alert("We Thank You For Your Report!\n" + data);

 })
 .fail(function() {

   alert("Error!!!!!!!");
 });
 


});

Comment: You must declare the "contextMenus" permission in your app's manifest to use the API.

Comment: also try this `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(itemData) {
  if (itemData.menuItemId == "item0"){
    /*your code/*}
  if (itemData.menuItemId == "item1"){
     /*your code*/}
});`

Comment: how do i know which is the menuID for the "Report a Scam Image"?

Comment: you have add an `id` property for your menu while creating contextMenu.  Add `id:'rprtimg'` below `title` property. Then use the id's value to check which menu is clicked on click event.